# Macro stopped searching for the same word after vbNo

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, lowercase

Good day VBA masters

May I ask for your help regarding my Code?

As you can see below, my code meant to search for words in a specific header style only and then convert it to lowercase.

My problem is once I choose "No" in the message box, my macro stopped searching for the same word in the next header.

My document does have multiple headers and I need to search for the same word until the last header of the document.

I follow an SOP so I cant convert all of the words in lowercase.

Hoping you can help me with my problem. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub ChangeCase1()
    Dim StrFind As String, StrRepl As String
    Dim i As Long
    StrFind = "And,Aboard,About,Above,Across,After,Against,Along,Alongside,Amid,Amidst,Among,Around,As,Aside,At,Athwart,Atop,Barring,Before,BehindBelow,Off,On,Onto,Opposite,Out,Outside,Beneath,Beside,Besides,Between,Beyond,But,By,Circa,Concerning,Despite,Down,During,Except,Following,For,From,In,Inside,Into,Like,Mid,Minus,Near,Next,Notwithstanding,Of,Worth,Over,Pace,Past,Per,Plus,Regarding,Round,Since,Than,Through,Throughout,Till,Times,To,Toward,Towards,Under,Underneath,Unlike,Until,Up,Upon,Versus,Via,With,Within,Without"
    Set RngTxt = Selection.Range
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, ","))
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Forward = True
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .Text = Split(StrFind, ",")(i)
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("K-Heading Level 1")
            .Execute
            While .Found
                If MsgBox("Replace " & Split(StrFind, ",")(i), vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                    Selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
                    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                    .Execute
                Else
                    GoTo Continue
                End If
            Wend

        End With
Continue:
    Next i
    Call ChangeCase2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day and welcome on board.

Here are some edits that should be made:

1. After your code finds something, it selects it. So, when you ask it
   to search again, it searches inside the selection from the last search result. You already have the `Selection.Collapse` statement that does that in `vbYes` case. You just need to apply it in the case of `vbNo` too.
2. To make sure the code will search for one word till the end of the document and that it will not start over, you should change `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` to `.Wrap = wdFindStop`.
3. To make sure the code will search for each word from the beginning of the document to its end, you should change `With Selection.Find` to `With ActiveDocument.Content.Find`

So, your code should be:

```
Sub ChangeCase1()
    Dim StrFind As String, StrRepl As String
    Dim i As Long
    StrFind = "And,Aboard,About,Above,Across,After,Against,Along,Alongside,Amid,Amidst,Among,Around,As,Aside,At,Athwart,Atop,Barring,Before,BehindBelow,Off,On,Onto,Opposite,Out,Outside,Beneath,Beside,Besides,Between,Beyond,But,By,Circa,Concerning,Despite,Down,During,Except,Following,For,From,In,Inside,Into,Like,Mid,Minus,Near,Next,Notwithstanding,Of,Worth,Over,Pace,Past,Per,Plus,Regarding,Round,Since,Than,Through,Throughout,Till,Times,To,Toward,Towards,Under,Underneath,Unlike,Until,Up,Upon,Versus,Via,With,Within,Without"    
    Set RngTxt = Selection.Range
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, ","))
        With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Forward = True
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .Text = Split(StrFind, ",")(i)
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("K-Heading Level 1")
            .Execute
            While .Found
                If MsgBox("Replace " & Split(StrFind, ",")(i), vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                    Selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
                End If
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Execute
            Wend
        End With
    Next i
    'Call ChangeCase2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However it still doesn't continue searching for the same word to the next header after selecting "no" in the message box (macro stopped searching for "And" to the next header after I selected no). Was it because of GoTo Continue?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I modified the position of "Continue" to make it look for the next occurrence of the same word, not the next one. Deleting it and the GoTo statement would do the trick too.

Comment: I tried to delete, now it doesn't stop searching for the same word until I select "yes"

Comment: Then you should change the `.Wrap = wdFindContinue` to `.Wrap = wdFindStop` To make the code stop searching for the same word once it reaches the end of the document. Also, add `Selection.HomeKey wdStory` before the first `.Excute` to make the code start searching from the top of the document. Check the new edits.

Comment: Apologies but after applying the changes above still gave me the same issue.

Comment: My apologies. The `.Execute` should be called whether you select yes or no. I fixed its position now. Please let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, code above is now working perfectly fine and has eliminated the issue .